# AggregateException when calling GetApplicationDefaultAsync()

Tags: c#, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I am trying to run the [sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/tree/master/vision/textDetection/) Vision API project. I basically copied and pasted the code `Program.cs` into my application and executed it.

This line (which is line #36-#37 [in `Program.cs`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dotnet-docs-samples/blob/master/vision/textDetection/Program.cs))

```
GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefaultAsync().Result;
```

throws a `System.AggregateException` in `mscorlib.dll` with `Additional information: One or more errors occurred.`.

By examining `InnerException`, I found out that the actual exception thrown is `InvalidOperationException` with `Error deserializing JSON credential data.`.

Nonetheless, my cloud project is a basic project, with a Service Account, and Cloud Vision API enabled, nothing else. I checked that my environment variable was set to the JSON file by writing:

```
Console.WriteLine(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"));
```

before the line above. The output of that (just before the crash) is (something like):

> `C:\Users\me\Documents\Projects\MyProject\MyProject-ba31aae6efa1.json`

I checked the file, and it is the file that I got when I enabled my service account. Every property in it looks fine (i.e. project name is correct, path's correct, ...).

I installed the Google Cloud SDK and executed `gcloud beta auth application-default login` and authorized access to my cloud account.

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By examining the detailed build log, I found out that the packages for the Google APIs had a dependency for `Newtonsoft.Json` version `9.0.1` (the latest at the time of this writing).

For whatever reason, the Google APIs *packages* have a dependency (which is installed along with them) on `Newtonsoft.Json` version `7.0.0`.

**The packages came with the wrong version!**

Installing the latest version (`9.0.1` in this case) fixes the issue.